# aws cloud formation create env using account id

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have a AWS account created under an Organization. `Say Account ID : 12345`. It is a parent account. Now i have new Role created, `Say Account ID : 67890`. I have switched my role from parent account to the new one. But when i execute the cloud formation template from AWS cli. It is still trying to create env in my parent account (`i.e,12345`) instead of the new account.

My question is - How can i execute/create env using CFT from AWS Cli in my new account (`ie, 67890`) ?  or is there a way to specify Account id in which the env should be created ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most likely forgot to configure your AWS CLI to use credentials from the linked account. You may create a new profile and specify it when you run the CLI command. Example:

```
aws configure --profile=account2
aws --profile=account2 cloudformation create-stack ...
```

If you are unable to setup an IAM credential on Account2, you may try to setup CLI to use the cross-account role you already have. You'll need to manually add the following block to your `~/.aws/config` file:

```
[profile account2]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/account2role
source_profile = account1
```

Replace `123456789012` and `account2role` with their corresponding values.

Comment: But the problem is - both the Account1 and Account2 has the same credentials. What i do is, Login to Account 1 and click switch role and go to Account 2 and create AWS resource.

Comment: I could execute the CFT in AWS console after switching to Account2. But from AWS cli i could not.

Comment: 2 accounts don't share the same IAM credentials. You need to create an IAM user in Account2 and generate credentials (AccessKey/SecretAccessKey) for it, then configure your AWS CLI as suggested.

Comment: Logged in as:    
backtrack
Account:
12345
 
Currently active as:  
backtrackDev
Account:
67890   I do not have privileges to create iam user :(

Comment: @Backtrack: updated the answer. Please, try the suggestion and let me know.

Comment: yes - Thanks or the answer, I found this in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-cli.html and tried it and worked for me